# Can the sum of a number, and a percentage of the same number rounded up be reversed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, algebra

I'm trying to run a calculation backwards. The function for getting a number is:

```js
const getPrice = (num, percentage) => num + ((Math.ceil(num/100)*100)*percentage)

getPrice(1000, 0.03) // returns 1,030
getPrice(32245, 0.03) // returns 33,214
getPrice(52143.23,0.03) // 53709.23
```

In plain terms it returns the sum of a number and a percentage of that number rounded up to the nearest hundred.

Is it possible to get the base price (the input, num) give the result of the function?

```js
 const getBasePrice = (num, percentage) => {return insertLogicHere}

 getBasePrice(1030, 0.03) // returns 1000
 getBasePrice(33214, 0.03) // returns 32245
 getBasePrice(53709.23,0.03) // returns 52143.23
```

I know this is more of a math question than a purely Javascript question but I'm not sure how to format this for a Math audience. I haven't been able to figure this one out even with the help of some other programmers at work.

Comment: Yes it is possible. The `Math.ceil(num/100)*100)` part can be replaced by just `num`. So basically you just do `A + (A*B)` And that can simply calculated back.

Comment: @wayneOS do you mean `A - (A*B)`? `1000` is less than `1030`?

Comment: No, you can't restore information lost during rounding

Comment: @evolutionxbox. Yes. But it gets even easier `A = C / (1 + B)`. For your example `1000 = 1030 / (1 + 0.03)`

Comment: @wayneOS - Math.ceil(num/100)*100) rounds the number to the nearest hundred. In the example of 1000 it has no effect, but for the value 32245, it becomes 32300. It's still necessary in the function.

Comment: @TomParke. No, [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) rounds to the nearest integer. EDIT: Sorry, you are right. i didn't saw the bracelet before *100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
By using the existing getPrice method you can work out the difference between the original and new values and reverse it exactly:

```js
const getPrice = (num, percentage) => num + ((Math.ceil(num/100)*100)*percentage)
const getBasePrice = (num, percentage) => {return Math.floor(num/(1+percentage))}

let num = 53709.23
let percentage = 0.03

let initialReverse = getBasePrice(num, percentage)
let finalReverse = initialReverse - (getPrice(initialReverse, percentage) - num)

console.log(finalReverse) //returns 52143.23
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm liking how simple this solution is, but it looks like the solution will be off by 3 or less with an percentage of 0.03. Is there a way to check the answer back again using getPrice to confirm the answer, and then recalculate based on the difference created? I think there's something to this.

Comment: @TomParke I've edited my solution to what I think you meant

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've also provided my own solution. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, however you will have differences because of rounding.

```js
const getBasePrice = (num, percentage) => {return (Math.round((100*num)/(((percentage*100)+100))))}

console.log(getBasePrice(1030, 0.03)) // returns 1000
console.log(getBasePrice(33214, 0.03)) // returns 32245
```

**EDIT**

If you remove the rounding is and exact match. Maybe you could do it like this when you are making the opperations and apply a format latter when you want to show this values.

```js
const getPrice = (num, percentage) => num + (num/100)*100*percentage

console.log(getPrice(1000, 0.03)) // returns 1,030
console.log(getPrice(32245, 0.03)) // returns 33212.35
console.log(getPrice(1244.124, 0.03)) // returns 1281.4477200000001


const getBasePrice = (num, percentage) => ((100*num)/(((percentage*100)+100)))

console.log(getBasePrice(1030, 0.03)) // returns 1000
console.log(getBasePrice(33212.35, 0.03)) // returns 32245
console.log(getBasePrice(1281.4477200000001, 0.03)) // returns 1244.124
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rubén.  As I replied above, it looks like the solution will be off by 3 or less with an percentage of 0.03. Is there a way to check the answer back again using getPrice to confirm the answer, and then recalculate based on the difference created? I think there's something to it.

Comment: @TomParke I'll added additional info in my response. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I called my mum and she helped me figure it out. There are some more specific variable names here and decimals are being fixed because we're working with dollars.

```js
const getBasePrice = (num, percent) => {
  const guess = num / (1 + percent);
  const roundUp = Math.ceil(guess / 100) * 100;
  const stampDuty = roundUp * percent;
  return parseFloat((num - stampDuty).toFixed(2));
};
```

With tests:

```js
const getPrice = (num, percentage) => {
  return num + Math.ceil(num / 100) * 100 * percentage;
}
const getBasePrice = (num, percent) => {
  const guess = num / (1 + percent);
  const roundUp = Math.ceil(guess / 100) * 100;
  const stampDuty = roundUp * percent;
  return parseFloat((num - stampDuty).toFixed(2));
};

const testFunction = () => {
  const percent = 0.03
  const number = parseFloat((Math.random() * 100000).toFixed(2))
  const stampDutyPrice = getPrice(number,percent)
  const backNumber = getBasePrice(stampDutyPrice,percent)
  
  return number === backNumber
}

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(testFunction() ? 'test passed' : 'text failed')
}
```